# network render client crashed. how to resume so PNGs still get generated from slaves

Tags: rendering, network

We have a job running with like 40 something slaves, I had to reboot my laptop that was running the client. What can I do to resume the PNGs getting outputted to the local folder as they were all night? I can't manage the job any longer it seems. is there a way to do that, such as add more blacklist slaves to the existing job?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: consider removing the _animation-nodes_ tag because your question has nothing to do with the _animation-nodes_ addon.